# Split string on white space

Tags: python, python-2.7, delimiter

I have this weird formatted text file I am trying to read in and I don't know how to tell python that each line begins with a delimiter.

A row in the text file look like:

```
     3.146    -1.339      .358    29.214
```

The file uses 5 spaces as the delimiter.  How can I read each line into a list with 4 items?

Comment: `line.strip().split()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` combined with `strip` to remove excess whitespace:

```
my_file_data = "     3.146    -1.339      .358    29.214"
data = my_file_data.strip().split('     ')
# do stuff with your data
print(data[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read each line into a list with 4 items using the following:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:

    # this will read in each row as:
    #
    #   ['3.146', '-1.339', '.358', '29.214']
    #
    # so `lines` will contain
    #
    #   [['3.146', '-1.339', '.358', '29.214'], ...]
    lines = map(str.split, f.readlines())

    # or alternatively, as @jez mentioned, it may be more readable to use
    lines = [ line.split() for line in lines ]

    # you'll then likely want to convert them to floats
    # 
    # this will give you:
    #
    #   [[3.146, -1.339, 0.358, 29.214], ...]
    data = [ map(float, split_line) for split_line in lines ]
```

Comment: `readlines()` will return a list.  You can't `split()` a list. You need to split each line in the list.

Comment: for readability, how about `lines = [ line.strip().split() for line in f ]`

Comment: Good point! In this case, since we're not using non-trivial lambdas (for which Guido holds such disdain), I think either is more or less equally readable (granted, `map` *is* less Pythonic...). If we want to add the `.strip()`, then certainly the LC is the better option. `.split()` should split on *all* whitespace in the line, so `strip` may not be necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your delimiter:

`delimiter='    '`

Then you just split your line of text using the delimiter

`lineoftext.split(delimiter)`